# QGIS autoremove unwanted space from data attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have an unwanted space in my data attribute field after copying the data as you see below.

[image]

Is there any way to remove it automatically (i.e. when I select another attribute field)?

Comment: Try `[trim](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=trim#trim)`. But once again, this works only after you created the entry to the attribute table, not while it "floats around".

Comment: Ok, I see, but how to apply it into the Defaults?  I have put something like this: trim('') but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your workflow and based on other suggestions/answer to use the **Trim** function, I would approach removing the space(s) in the following way.
Once the data copying to the attribute table is complete, I would simply use **Update existing field** from the **Field calculator**. Once complete simply save.

I tried it on QGIS 3.10.12 and it work. (Pls note create a back up before you update).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [`trim()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#trim) in default value, you have to generate a new field, for example `"span_name_2"`, where you write value with space.

And setting in `"span_name"` field as default value:

```
trim("span_name_2")
```

so automatically in 'span_name' is memorized text without space.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without creating the new column?